# I am trying to deploy a cloud function and getting this error 'Cannot read status of undefined'

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write function that sends data from firestore to google sheet. Here is my function in index.js:

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const { promisify } = require('util');
exports.loadInformation = functions.firestore.document('incident-report/{id}').onCreate((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.log('I am triggered')

    google.auth.getClient({
      scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'],
    }).then(auth => {
      const api = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth });
      const getSheets = promisify(api.spreadsheets.get.bind(api.spreadsheets));
      return getSheets({ spreadsheetId: '1hCF8jDt6uqYZ7qC93To2n0MbGzDWPIBU72IMp2xqh5Y' });
    })
      // This just prints out all Worksheet names as an example
      .then(({ data: { sheets } }) => {
        res.status(200).send({ sheets });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({ err });
      })
});
```

I get this following error. 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

How can I solve this? Is my function looks good.

Comment: try to check `err` variable first, it might have a message what's going wrong

Answer (score 3):

The Firestore `onCreate` trigger expects a handler (function) with two arguments and not four. The reason why it is complaining that `res` is undefined is because nothing is passed on that parameter since it is the third argument in a function that only passes two (DocumentSnapshot and EventContext). Give these documentations a read [GCP Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/extend-with-functions#event_triggers) and [Firebase Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events), it should steer you on the right track. Also notice that none of the examples use the common error-first callback style such as `(err, ...) => ...`

Answer (score 0):

Firestore's onCreate function is called with 2 arguments.

1. [Firestore DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference)
2. [Context](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.EventContext)

The arguments that your code is expecting are incorrect.
Also remove the `res.status(200).send()`. This part is for an`HTTPS` functions and not`Firestore onCreate` trigger.

Change them as follows:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const { promisify } = require('util');

exports.loadInformation = functions.firestore.document('incident-report/{id}').onCreate((doc, context) => {
  console.log('I am triggered')

  return google.auth.getClient({
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'],
  }).then(auth => {
    const api = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth });
    const getSheets = promisify(api.spreadsheets.get.bind(api.spreadsheets));
    return getSheets({ spreadsheetId: '1hCF8jDt6uqYZ7qC93To2n0MbGzDWPIBU72IMp2xqh5Y' });
  })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
});
```